# Function is not defined? But it actually is defined in the button

Tags: javascript, function, typeerror

My function says:

```
TypeError: Number(...) is not a function
    at calculateSpin (/script.js:4:45)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (/:21:57)
```

But to me(a very new coder) I don't see a problem with my function

Comment: Can I see your code, please? Maybe you can put more details here. How's the line with the `Number(...)` implementation?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58868963/function-is-not-defined-but-it-actually-is-defined-in-the-button) to add meaningful code and problem description. Posting a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Also, I assume since you're getting `.js` warning you're using either javascript. Could you also tag your question with the language you're using? See also: [ask]

Comment: I can't currently get my code but there is nothing in my code that says number(...) . I am not sure but I would think that it has something to do with my other number()'s.